# How can I center-align text with uneven icons either side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to center align the text in this image, ideally using as little CSS/HTML as possible. As you can see, the icons on the left push it off center:

[image: alignment problem]

Here's the relevant HTML and CSS for this top section:

```
<div class="navbarheader">
    <div class="header-left">
        <button type="button" class="pull-left btn-nav-menu">
            <i class="navbar-text fa fa-fw fa-navicon"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="pull-left" ng-click="ui.showSearch()">
            <i class="navbar-text fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="header-title">
        <div class="navbar-brand">{{ui.headerTitle}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
        <button class="btn-watchlist pull-right" ng-click="ui.toggleWatchlists()">
            <i class="navbar-text fa fa-fw fa-binoculars"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbarheader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.navbarheader .header-left {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
}
.navbarheader .header-title {
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbarheader .header-right {
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
```

Any ideas how to keep the text center aligned, but allow it to occupy all the blank space if necessary?

Worth mentioning this is in a Bootstrap 4.0 alpha codebase.

Comment: Little bit hacky, but couldn't you put the same icon in black on the right, which would balance it out, but not be seen?

Comment: Not sure what text do you want to center?

Comment: Any way you could post enough code to reproduce the problem or a working demo?

Comment: Give both left and right icon containers equal `flex-basis`,`flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`, add `white-space:nowrap` to the title and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys  - plenty of good answers below that work at this point so no further updates to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to make sure both `.header-right` and `.header-left` apply the same "flex" pressure on `.header-title`. Their `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` need to be equal. By default, they have  `flex:0 1 auto;` so you don't need to worry about `flex-grow`[`0`] and `flex-shrink`[`1`].

However, you need to change the `auto` into a practical value (anything translatable in `px` by the browser: `%`, `px`, `em`, `rem`,...), greater than `50%` (you can go below `50%` if you set `flex-grow:1;` on `.header-left` and `.header-right` - just remember to make them equal).

Your title, even though will have a resulting `flex-basis` of `0`, will grow eating up equally from left and right's width. Of course, you need to make sure it always stays on 1 line by adding `white-space:nowrap` to it (if it's really long and you think it should wrap on some very narrow screens place the `white-space` rule inside a `@media` query; also, remember to give your `.header-title` sufficient `flex-basis` when you allow it to wrap, so it doesn't wrap on too many lines - don't worry if your total `flex-basis` is larger than `100%`, all browsers will scale all elements down proportionally if the parent's `flex-wrap` is set to `nowrap`).

If you prefer CSS to English, here goes code:

```
.navbarheader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.header-right,
.header-left {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.header-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

And the prefixed (production ready) version:

```css
.navbarheader {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.header-right,
.header-left {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 50%;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
          flex-basis: 50%;
}
.header-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

But the relevant part is

```
.header-right, .header-left { flex-basis: 50%; }
```

Comment: Well explained. Multiple solutions. +1

Comment: @GustvandeWal It was too much theory, too little practice. I finally opted for a working solution, since guessing it will help a few people unfamiliar with Bootrasp 4 optional flex version. I hope you don't mind :).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted as a solution - something using the flex model and no hacks. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Distribute your headers in amounts you can live with without breaking responsiveness. so that you have a perfect amount to center with and an equal amount to each side to use as gutters or margins.

```
.navbarheader .header-left {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
    width:20%; /* adjust accordingly if it's too much. do the same in the other to complete 100% total */
    background: red;
}
.navbarheader .header-title {
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
    width:60%;
    background: yellow;
}
.navbarheader .header-right {
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
    width:20%;
    background: green;
}
```

See the [**demo**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/ZQaeRg) (I colored the backgrounds so that you can distinguish the distances)

Answer (score 1):

you could add a gap same size as icon missing:

```
.navbarheader > :last-child{
  margin-left:2.5rem;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEYqxx)

```css
/* background gradient added to visualize centers */

.navbarheader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 1em 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, gray 50%, lightgray 50%);
}
.navbarheader .header-left {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
}
.navbarheader .header-title {
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gray 50%, lightgray 50%);
}
.navbarheader .header-right {
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
.navbarheader >:last-child {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="navbarheader">
  <div class="header-left">
    <button type="button" class="pull-left btn-nav-menu">
      <i class="navbar-text fa fa-fw fa-navicon"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="pull-left" ng-click="ui.showSearch()">
      <i class="navbar-text fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="header-title">
    <div class="navbar-brand">whatever text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-right">
    <button class="btn-watchlist pull-right" ng-click="ui.toggleWatchlists()">
      <i class="navbar-text fa fa-fw fa-binoculars"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `position: absolute` on `header-title` and remove it from natural flow of elemnts so it will always be **centered** relatively to `navbarheader`

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="left">
    <a href="">Icon</a>
    <a href="">Icon</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  
  <div class="right">Icon</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `translate(-50%)`?

Answer (score -1):

Fix it with negative margins... center the text and the `margin-left` to minus the half of the left icons width.

Comment: Boom that worked. Can't believe I didn't think of that. I feel dumb now!

Comment: Really you should use a positive `margin-right` as the negative margin on the left will make the text overlap the icons on the left when you shrink your viewport